# auto scale aws EMR based on custom CloudWatch metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr, amazon-cloudwatch

Nowadays you can scale EMR cluster based on CloudWatch metrics, i.e https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/dynamically-scale-applications-on-amazon-emr-with-auto-scaling/.

Can you set the autoscale values based on custom CloudWatch metrics?
for example, use spark Waiting batches metrics?

Answer (score 0):

I got a response from AWS support, at this stage EMR doesn't support auto-scale based on custom metrics. 
The support asked the EMR team to add this capability.